# Use Linq to flatten name/value collection

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The IGrouping result below shows some sample form data. I'm storing Name/Value pairs in the database to collect form data.  The data below is a basic example of what I'm collecting from a user completing a form.

[image: LinqPad screenshot]
I would like have a linq query or SQL query that provides a flattened version of this data.  Example as csv data:

```
FirstName,LastName,Email,EmailVerify,Meta
sdfsdf,sdfsdf,yu@yu.com,yu@yu.com,
```

The records are related by EntryKey.  How can I get result data like the example above?  Thanks.

Comment: what if I typed my name as `this,is,my,name` ?

Comment: Erik - I'm just using the CSV format as a way to communicate the data structure.  Assume that's all being scrubbed.  CSV will put that in quotes, so that's the solve.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `EntryKey` if before that you are filtering for a specific `EntryKey`? Your group will contain one parent item only.

Comment: If your query is filtering on the key why group the data? Seems like it's already grouped by the filter.

Comment: You can do this much nicer with SQL... especially if your column field names are fixed.  Check out the `PIVOT` keyword.  Then use `.ExecuteQuery<T>(…)` and pass in a class that has property names that match your fields.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can do dynamic pivots in LINQ but they aren't pretty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565168/is-a-dynamic-pivot-using-linq-possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML or JSON serialization to achieve this. After serialization you can very easily convert the data into plain text

Following link help you to write the serialization and de-serialization code.

- [XML Serialization](http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/serialize-and-deserialize-list-generic-or-other-collections-in-csharp-c)
- [JSON Serialization](http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/code-to-convert-javascript-json-to-c-type)

**Update**
To get the property dynamically, you can use `ExpandoObject` (using System.Dynamic namespace), this will help you to define property dynamically. Once it is generated then you can serialize it to specified Type. Following is sample code that helps.

```
    var xNewExpando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

    foreach (var adv in advocateDetails)
    {
        xNewExpando.Add(adv.DetailName, adv.DetailValue);
    }

    var yourString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xNewExpando);
```

Comment: Thanks Totalo, I know how to serialize the data, but I'm trying to treat the objects as dynamic and set properties based on the DetailName fields.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have update my answer to meet your expectation. Please let me know if this work for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like:

```
var results = db.EntryDetails
  .GroupBy(ed => ed.EntryKey)
  .ToList()
  .Select(ek => new List<List<string>>()
    {
      ek.Select(gb => gb.DetailName).ToList(),
      ek.Select(gb => gb.DetailValue).ToList()
    });
  .SelectMany(ed => ed)
  .ToList();
```

The result will be a `List<List<string>>`.

The first `List<>` is each row.

The contents of each of these lists is a `List<string>` of columns.

Comment: Erik - I'm not trying to produce a CSV output per se - I just showed an example of the output in CSV format to show how I want the recordset to be output.